# How to find max continuous sequences with conditions in dataframe by pyspark?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to find maximal period of continuous periods for every customer where period must
be statuses from "start" to "long" or only with "start"

I tried to do it by my own. But i don't understand how to do it right.

```
v2 = (
    Window.partitionBy("customer_id")
    .orderBy("begin_date")
    .rangeBetween(Window.currentRow - 1, Window.currentRow)
)
```

```
df = (
    df.filter(F.col("status").isin(["start", "long"]))
    .orderBy(df.begin_date)
    .withColumn("dif", df.end_date - df.begin_date)
    .withColumn(
    "dif",
    F.when(
        (F.col("status") != "start"),
        F.sum(F.col("dif")).over(v2),
    ).otherwise(F.col("dif")))
```

For example i need convert dataframe "a" in dataframe "b". Can somebody helps me how to do it?

a)

```
+-----------+----------+--------+------+                                        
|customer_id|begin_date|end_date|status|
+-----------+----------+--------+------+
|          1|         1|       2| start|
|          1|         2|       3|  long|
|          1|         4|       5| start|
|          1|         5|       6|  long|
|          1|         6|      10|  long|
|          1|        10|      11|  long|
|          2|        10|      14| start|
|          1|        11|      12|  long|
|          2|        14|      15|  long|
|          2|        15|      20| start|
|          3|        16|      20| start|
|          3|        20|      32|  long|
|          1|        20|      40|  long|
|          3|        40|      41| start|
|          3|        41|      44|  long|
+-----------+----------+--------+------+
```

b)

```
+-----------+----------+--------+------+---+                                    
|customer_id|begin_date|end_date|status|dif|
+-----------+----------+--------+------+---+
|          1|         1|       2| start|  1|
|          1|         2|       3|  long|  2|
|          1|         4|       5| start|  1|
|          1|         5|       6|  long|  2|
|          1|         6|      10|  long|  6|
|          2|        10|      14| start|  1|
|          1|        10|      11|  long|  2|
|          1|        11|      12|  long|  3|
|          2|        14|      15|  long|  4|
|          2|        15|      20| start|  1|
|          3|        16|      20| start|  1|
|          3|        20|      32|  long| 13|
|          3|        40|      41| start|  1|
|          3|        41|      44|  long|  4|
+-----------+----------+--------+------+---+
```

Comment: In the first dataframe it has 14 lines, in the second 15. why? You can give more details about the rule?

Comment: Need to find max continuous sequence for every user (sequence must starts from row with status = "created" and continues with rows with status = "long" where end_date of previous row should be equal to begin_date of current row).